# Full page background only on home/index page

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have an interesting problem.. I have a typical single page app, where inside index.html, i have my header, footer and , using ui-router to inject views.

When users are on the homepage (index.html), how can i have a full page background on the ... And on any other pages, that background is not there (white).

html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">

    <header>            
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><button>Login</button></li>
                <li><button>Tell Me More!</button></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>


    <main>
        <section class="container">
            <div ui-view /></div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <footer>
            <ul>
                <li>Contact Us</li>
                <li>About Us</li>
            </ul>
    </footer>


    <script src="/assets/js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/vendor/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/vendor/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/all.min.js"></script> 

</body>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        .state('index', {
            url: '/index',
            templateUrl: 'partial/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })

        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'partial/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
});
```

Comment: Spawn the image as absolute from home.html view - then that's the only page it will show on

Answer (score 1):

You can apply different styles or images for different pages by setting `$rootScope` variables that will be inherited by the scopes of the controllers or by sending some styling parameters to different states through the UIrouter), then you will use those settings in the views to apply your styles/images.

**Short note:** when the users are on the homepage, **they are NOT** in *index.html* but in the state that you define as being the homepage *(you had this assumption in your initial question)*.

A few samples:

**Option 1** - settings in $rootScope

in your module's `app.run(...)` you listen to the state change events and set some variables for your specific routes, ie:

```
angular.module('yourModuleNameHere').run(function($rootScope, ...
 //some global settings here:
 $rootScope.isHome = false;
 $rootScope.hasInnerHeader = false;
 $rootScope.bodyClass = "";
 $rootScope.bodyStyle = "";


 // Page change - specific settings
 $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {
  //some other processing you may need 
  switch ($state.current.name) {
        case 'main.home':
            $rootScope.headerClass = 'home-header';
            $rootScope.isHome = true;
            $rootScope.bodyClass = "home-body background-full";                
            break;
        default:
            //some default settings
 }
```

and you can use those settings directly in your partial files:

```
<div id="header" class="{{headerClass}}">...some header content here....</div>
```

because the partial scope inherits the $rootScope.

**Option 2** - send parameters from UIrouter (you may get them from a config file, inject it as a provider in your `app.config`)

Set some page specific data for your route:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/index',
        templateUrl: 'partial/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController',
        pageSettings: {
            bodyClass: "homepage-class";
        }
    })
```

and in the partial controller you consume it like this:

*don't forget to inject the dependency for `$state`*

```
function _init() {
    // ***** Route params check *******
    if ($state.current.pageSettings && $state.current.pageSettings.bodyClass)   {
     //do something with the class, ie: put it in the scope:
     $scope.myPartialClass = $state.current.pageSettings.bodyClass

     //or switch through different settings
        switch ($state.current.pageSettings.bodyClass) {
            case "homepage-class":
                $scope.hideSomeDiv = true;
                $scope.anotherSetting = false;
                break;
            case "homepage-fullscreen-class":
                $scope.hideSomeDiv = false;
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
}

_init();//call the init method
```

**PROs:** these methods allow you to have specific styling for different pages, change some layout options, customize them from a config file, etc

**CONs:** you need a little more work, not quite necessary if you only need to style a single page

*note: code above is not tested but should give you an idea*

Comment: Useful info. Interested to see the response. Whats the pro/con of this approach over @DarrenSweeney's

Comment: I updated the answer. @DarrenSweeney's solution is simpler, I guess

Comment: now I realize that your question has another meaning: how to change the entire layout of the app when going to a specific route. That requires a totally different answer based on UIrouter states and views.